# MASM SEG operator

Tags: assembly, masm

Let's assume we are writing assembly code using MASM 6.1 / 16 bit / huge data model, and we have a variable (label) named MY_VAR, a segment named MY_SEG and a segment group named MY_GROUP. Let's assume MY_VAR is placed in MY_SEG, and MY_SEG belongs to MY_GROUP.

Then, what is the difference between the following two statements:

```
1) MOV AX, MY_SEG
2) MOV AX, SEG MY_SEG:MY_VAR
```

Furthermore, what is the difference between the following two statements:

```
1) MOV AX, MY_GROUP
2) MOV AX, SEG MY_GROUP:MY_VAR
```

Note: MASM happily processes all of these statements. As expected (in my case), the results of each 1) and 2) are the same. But I would like to know for sure ...

Thank you very much,

Binarus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MASM the label `MY_VAR` translates to the offset part of the address of MY_VAR relative to the segment it was declared in (if you use it like `mov ax, MY_VAR`) or relative the to segment you have assumed for the segment register you are using to access it (if you use it like `mov ax, WORD PTR [MY_VAR]`).

As you know a given variable (in general a linear address) has multiple logical address, for example the variable at `8000h` linear can be accessed as `0800h:0000h` or `0700h:1000h` and so so.
The form `MY_SEG:MY_VAR` tell the assembler to compute the offset relative to the segment `MY_SEG`. So if MY_SEG starts at `7000h` linear, `MY_SEG2` starts at `6000h` linear  then for a var MY_VAR at `8000h` linear `MY_SEG:MY_VAR` is 1000h and `MY_SEG2:MY_VAR` is 2000h.

The `SEG` directive compute the segment part of the logical address instead of the offset, it is the segment MASM used (again by the rules given above) to compute the offset.

In your first instructions you are telling MASM to put the address (let's leaving relocation behind) of the segment `MY_SEG` in AX (so if the segment starts at 5000h the value in AX is 500h).
In your second instructions your are explicit telling MASM to use the segment MY_SEG in computing the offset of `MY_VAR` and then, by the `SEG` directive, telling it to return the segment part instead, that is `MY_SEG`.

So they are the same but the second one is redundant.

Comment: I always thought that MY_VAR is syntactically equivalent to OFFSET MY_VAR. If I am right (probably I am not), that would mean that MY_VAR translates to the offset relative to the segment in MASM 5, but to the offset relative to the group in MASM 6. Could you please add some more detail here (and perhaps correct my wrong assumption)?

Comment: @user3239842 I'd like to but I don't have MASM anymore to do a quick test. AFAIR in MASM when you do `mov ax, [MY_VAR]` the assembler look for the segment you have declared MY_VAR into and use that for the offset computation. You must have used `ASSUME` with the segment of MY_VAR, eventually the assembler generate a Segment Override Prefix. With groups the algo is slightly different, look [here](http://www.oopweb.com/Assembly/Documents/ArtOfAssembly/Volume/Chapter_8/CH08-3.html#HEADING3-192). If you use `mov ax, MY_VAR` I think the offset is always relative to the segment of MY_VAR

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's a nice and easy to understand summary of what I have learned in a much harder way from the MASM 6 documentation. To remove ambiguity, I now have changed all my standalone assembly code in the following way: There is no place without valid ASSUME directives any more, and whenever SEG or OFFSET is taken, the symbols' names are given in qualified form, i.e. MY_GROUP:MY_VAR or MY_SEG_MYVAR. I still have a related problem with inline assembly because we obviously can't use ASSUME or the qualified notation there, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803553)

Comment: ... and I am doing all addressing in qualified form, like MOV AX,[DS:MY_VAR] instead of MOV AX, [MY_VAR]. Together with the correct ASSUMES, my code should now be bullet-proof.