# about MASM seg operator

Tags: assembly, masm, segment, memory-segmentation

I found this in the book "Art of x86 assembly" page 393:

> "The seg operator does two things. First, it extracts the segment
> portion of the specified address, second, it converts the type of
> the specified expression from address to con- stant."

It says that the `seg` operator does convert the expr (the address) to constant, but when i tried to assemble this :

```
code segment
        assume cs: code             
message db "Hello World!$"
    db (seg $) dup ('H') 
_start:
code ends
end
```

I've got this error:

```
a.asm(4) : error A2026: constant expected .
```

so seg do not convert the address to constant?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [masm seg operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800744/masm-seg-operator).

Comment: Not all "constants" are equivalent. Depending on the setting (com / exe / 16-bit / 32-bit / etc), segments are likely to be assigned either by the linker or when the program is loaded, so they are "link/load time constants" and can only be used in specific ways for which relocations are provided. Typically this includes simple arithmetic (e.g. add a constant offset) but not much else.  This as opposed to "assembly time constants" which should be possible to use in any way that a literal number could be used.